# Set the Height of an IFRAME based on its Document's Height (Cross Domain)

Tags: javascript, html

I tried using the top.location.hash approach to have a site on a different domain (also within an iframe) set the top windows hash value to its own height, but I've now discovered this isn't cross domain safe.

What other options do I have to make sure that the iframe constantly resets it's height when the iframe document is finished loading?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [window.postMessage()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.postMessage) to communicate across domains. See http://caniuse.com/#search=postmessage for the current level of support - pretty much all browsers and even MSIE starting with MSIE 8.

Comment: won't help much, needs to be an IE7 compatible solution. Thanks

Comment: That's a pity. However, if you don't find a better solution you can still fall back to a fixed size in IE7 while having it work properly everywhere else.